# Without having knowledge on previous versions of Drupal can I learn Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

Drupal organization has announced the release date of Drupal 8 (November 19, 2015).

I really thought of learning Drupal but because of some or the other reason I have been delaying it so far but Drupal 8 is about to release now and I want to learn the most popular CMS.

I know YII2 and Joomla so, can it be easy for me to learn Drupal 8 or shall I learn the previous versions of Drupal and then go for Drupal 8 ?

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: Go for Drupal 8 directly if you want to learn it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, even I think the same.

Comment: I don't know why this question got down votes. I just want guidance  from drupal experts.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has vast changes when compared to its predecessors. For now, it has released its 8.0.0-rc2. Documentation is getting updated and it is still in progress. However as a front-end user, it would be easier to migrate from Drupal 7 to 8 as it has added many contributed modules to core modules. But for a developer, 8 uses TWIG and has made some changes in module/theme development. Till now, modules are also released as candidates.

It depends, if you want to create an application instantly, then for now, go for current version, or if you can wait, you can learn the basics now and can migrate yourself to 8 easily. Drupal's [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation) and [API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8) can also be accessed!

> Learning is not at all a waste! It will be useful in any ways!

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion dear

Answer (score 1):

Difference between D8 and D7 is much bigger than difference between D7 and D6. Back-end interface does look very familiar, but under the hood there is significant difference because of symphony and twig laying there.

So experience from D7 may be useful, but if you are going to work only with D8 then there is no purpose of learning D7 first, because some things may be working differently.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest difference from 7 to 8 is the object-oriented approach of Drupal 8. As a developer without knowledge of older versions of Drupal, I think it is better to dive in Drupal 8 directly. Please be aware of the steep learning curve of Drupal though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will make sure I'm aware of the steeps.